# Can I customize the message shown at the bottom while multi tasking in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multitasking

I am currently developing an iOS app and was just wondering can the message displayed during multi tasking in iOS (Switching from one app to another) is customizable ?

I see WhatsApp and Facebook display Good morning, Good afternoon type texts, so I guess it is customizable but did not find anything regarding that how to do it or how can I add it to my App.

[image]

Comment: You cannot customize that text yet. The "Good Morning" and "Good Afternoon" texts are there because the system determined that you usually open a particular app in that time of the day.

Comment: (I didn't write this as an answer because I've already answered this question before, but I can't find the duplicate.)

Comment: Oh alright, Thank you. I thought the "Good Morning" and "Good Afternoon" texts where customized by the respective developers. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You welcome. I found the duplicate, please accept it as such.